# Adding to a 2D Array

Tags: java

How would I go about adding two elements into a 2D Array while looping.

```
for(...){
gradeArray[i][i] (gradeArray[95][5]  <---- i = 0, gets the zero term for the grade and frequency 
gradeArray[i][i] (gradeArray[96][2] <-----i = 1; gets the first term for the grade and frequency
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you aren't using an object-oriented design?

Comment: I'm a noob, what can I say :P

Comment: It's not clear from your question (to me at least) what the two dimensions of your array represent, and what values you want to store in it. Are grade and frequency two distinct lists, or do they relate to each other in some way? If so, how? Like, does each grade occurs with a certain frequency (30% of the students got a B?), or a grade is assigned to each frequency (99.7 MHz is grade 'medium popular'), or a value is assigned to each combination of grade and frequency (grade 'AA' bonds with frequency of 'monthly' dividends cost $50), etc.

Comment: Wouldn't you want each grade to appear only once (along with its frequency) in the combined data set? Your data structure has each (grade, frequency) pair occurring as many times as the grade occurs in the initial data. What are you really after?

Comment: @Jay, The grades are randomly generated and the frequency is the number of times it occurs. They relate to each other directly and they should be in the same Array,  such as a 2D Array. That way I am able to loop down the list and add each grade and its' corresponding frequency.

Comment: You should search/read more before asking questions.

Comment: @Ted Hopp, Yes I have realized the grades do appear more than once but I have a method to shortening the list into unique grades instead of repeats. I'm really just asking is there a way to add two elements to an array at the same time or different(doesn't matter).

Comment: Your updated question makes no sense at all. What is the relationship between the four integers `i`, `95`, `5`, and `gradeArray[95][5]` (when `i` == 0)? Likewise between `i`, `96`, `2`, and `gradeArray[96][2]` when `i` == 1? What do "zero term" and "first term" mean?

Answer (score 5):

It seems to me that you want to know the number of times each grade occurs. I think that your best bet will be a HashMap:

```
Map<Integer, Integer> frequencyTable = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
for (Integer grade : gradeArray) {
    if (!frequencyTable.containsKey(grade)) {
        frequencyTable.put(grade, Collections.frequency(gradeArray, grade));
    }
}
```

Comment: This is better because a Map is a data structure that better represents the data you are storing. Each grade is directly tied to a single frequency. If you have two lists, you could (easily) end up with lists that are out of synch.

Answer (score 1):

Your new edit is still confusing to me, but this is all that I can think that you are asking:

```
int[][] gradesAndFrequencies = new int[gradeCount][2];
for (int i = minGrade; i < maxGrade; i++) {
    int grade = ?;
    int frequency = ?;
    gradesAndFrequencies[i][0] = grade;
    gradesAndFrequencies[i][1] = frequency;
}
```

This is assuming you know how many grades there are in total, that you know how to find each grade and its frequency.

I still stand by my previous comment on Ted Hopp's answer: without any additional info on what it is you are trying to do, I have to say that this is not really a good model of your data.

Answer (score 0):

You're not gonna like it, but here's how.
So, arrays are immutable. So, to avoid this issue, I'd use an ArrayList, which is mutable. But to answer your question (assuming the dimensions are 95x95):

```
int newGradeArray[][] = new int[96][96]; //creating a new array that has an extra column and row, for more space.
for(int i = 0; i < 95; i++)//a set of nested loops taking everything from the old array, and moving it to this new one.
    for(int j = 0; j < 95; j++)
        newGradeArray[i][j] = gradeArray[i][j]
//now to add the elements (in the new element or column, your choice)
newGradeArray[95][95] = 95; //assigns the very edge of the new array a value of 95
```

Or, you can use an ArrayList.
This way, you don't need to make a new array and reassign, you can do something like:

```
ArrayList<Integer> a = new ArrayList<Integer>(); //note: ArrayLists can only have classes, not primitive types. Luckily, Integer and I think Character are classes too!
a.add(95, new Integer(95)); //sets the index of 95 as an Integer: 95.
```

And these can be made 2 dimensional.
Or:

```
ArrayList<int[]> i = new ArrayList<int[]>();
```

Or even:
    ArrayList> l = new ArrayList>();
If you want :)

Hope this helped!

Answer (score -3):

just use 2 lists, one for grades and one for frequency

use:

```
List<Integer> grades = new ArrayList<Integer>();
List<Integer> freq = new ArrayList<Integer>();
grades.add(grade);
freq.add(frequency);
```

to add to them

it would be a lot simpler.

example:

```
while(1 == 1) //infinite loop
{
    grade = -1
    frequency = -1
    grade = inputGrade.nextInt();
    frequency = inputFrequency.nextInt();
    if(grade != -1 && frequency != -1)
    {
        grades.add(grade);
        freq.add(frequency);
    }
    else
    {
    //if using a command window
    System.out.println("Missing either frequency or grade, values not stored");
    //if not using a command window
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Missing either frequency or grade, values not stored");
    }
}
```

Comment: That's not two arrays, but two lists

Comment: I think lists would do just fine in this situation, but yes they aren't arrays.

Comment: I think this is a terrible design. What's to link the grade to the frequency? You are basically hoping that your indexes never get out of synch....

Comment: just write them accuratly, and input a null for any missing values.

Comment: Yes, I am trying to keep them linked together. But is there not a way to add to elements to an array at the same time?

Comment: @RustyTheBoyRobot If the number of grades is fixed, this would work. If you want to be safe, then yes, you'd use a HashMap.

Comment: @EnviousNoob Okay, well could you answer Jay's and TedHopp's questions above? There seems to be a bit of confusion as to what you're trying to do.

Comment: If working accessing the list multithreaded, I would recommend using synchronized blocks when modifying the lists :)